My 2003 Honda Accord just stopped cranking the other day, won’t turn over at all, has to be pushed while I pop the clutch to start it, what do I do?
I have a 2003 Honda Accord Lx, got a new battery last month, topped all fluids, put new bulbs in it and it was doing fine. The other day all of a sudden it wouldn’t crank. Tried jumping it, tried doing that stick thing directly to the starter and nothing. Lights and everything still worked. My friend pushed the car with it in first gear and me holding the clutch down and all brakes off and at a good speed I popped the clutch and she started. That’s the only way to start her now…what do I do to fix it? Don’t wanna waste money I don’t have on something and that’s not the issue…. Please help… oh and now my battery is almost dead from the lights in the car coming on every time the door opens or anything

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Do as Paulster says. And meanwhile, if you need to push-start it again before it's repaired, please stop using first gear to start it. That's a lot of stress on the drivetrain, and you could break something. Choose the gear below top gear for the least stressful start, such as 3rd if it's a 4-speed, 4th if it's a 5-speed, etc. It works fine and your drive train will thank you for it.

From your description, I'd suggest you have a bad starter. Before you change it out, though, I'd suggest you get it tested. If you hooked power up to it directly and it did nothing, this seems like a pretty good indicator. Take the starter off the vehicle and take it down to a parts store to have it tested. You can also bench test it off of the car by taking a battery and jumper cables, attach the negative to the case of the starter and the positive to the larger lug on the solenoid. Then using a screwdriver, jump between the large lug and the smaller one. The small one will activate the solenoid, causing the starter to kick over. If it's doing nothing, then you'll want to replace the starter.
About the battery, you'll want to ensure it is fully charged before going forward. I'd suggest you get it on a slow charge (2A) for a couple of days. Trying to start the car with a low battery is not a good thing.
